# oracle group by clause with filter

Tags: sql, oracle

I have data like this in table,

```
`dept       id            rank
CSE        1             1
CSE        2             2
CSE        3             3
CSE        4             4
CSE        5             5
CSE        6             6
CSE        7             7
CSE        8             8
MECH       9             1
MECH       10           2
MECH       11           3
MECH       12           4
MECH       13           5
MECH       14           6
MECH       15           7
MECH       16           8
ELEC       17           6`
```

I want output like this:

```
`dept       r1           r2           r3           r4           r5           r6           r7           r8                         

dept       1/1         1/2         1/3         1/4         1/5         1/6         1/7         1/8

MECH       1/1         1/2         1/3         1/4         1/5         1/6         1/7         1/8

ELEC       0/1         0/2         0/3         0/4         0/5         1/6         0/7         0/8
`
```

I know i should use group by and count but unable to find a solution. Can someone please help with this oracle query.

select with group and filter

Comment: what have you tried so far ?  I'd recommend using PIVOT, not GROUP BY .. take a look into PIVOT and see if you can wrestle a solution out ;)  https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6__CHDCEJJE   (hint: the solution with pivot is VERY trivial ;) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `PIVOT`:

```sql
SELECT dept,
       r1 || '/1' AS r1,
       r2 || '/2' AS r2,
       r3 || '/3' AS r3,
       r4 || '/4' AS r4,
       r5 || '/5' AS r5,
       r6 || '/6' AS r6
FROM   (SELECT dept, rank FROM table_name)
PIVOT (
  COUNT(*)
  FOR rank IN (1 AS r1, 2 AS r2, 3 AS r3, 4 AS r4, 5 AS r5, 6 AS r6)
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (dept, id, rank) AS
SELECT 'CSE',   1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CSE',   2, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CSE',   3, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CSE',   4, 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CSE',   5, 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CSE',   6, 6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CSE',   7, 7 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CSE',   8, 8 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'MECH',  9, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'MECH', 10, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'MECH', 11, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'MECH', 12, 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'MECH', 13, 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'MECH', 14, 6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'MECH', 15, 7 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'MECH', 16, 8 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ELEC', 17, 6 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| DEPT | R1 | R2 | R3 | R4 | R5 | R6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CSE | 1/1 | 1/2 | 1/3 | 1/4 | 1/5 | 1/6 |
| MECH | 1/1 | 1/2 | 1/3 | 1/4 | 1/5 | 1/6 |
| ELEC | 0/1 | 0/2 | 0/3 | 0/4 | 0/5 | 1/6 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/sr3Bj7GT)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option; read comments within code.

This is your sample data, a little bit simplified:

```
SQL> with test (dept, id, rank) as
  2    (select 'CSE', 1, 1 from dual union all
  3     select 'CSE', 2, 2 from dual union all
  4     select 'CSE', 3, 3 from dual union all
  5     select 'CSE', 4, 4 from dual union all
  6    --
  7    select 'MECH',  9, 1 from dual union all
  8    select 'MECH', 10, 2 from dual union all
  9    select 'MECH', 11, 3 from dual union all
 10    select 'MECH', 12, 4 from dual union all
 11    --
 12    select 'ELEC', 17, 2 from dual
 13    ),
```

Query begins here. Create combination of all `DEPT` and `RANK` values (it'll be used later, in outer join):

```
 14  --
 15  all_depts as
 16    (select distinct dept from test),
 17  all_ranks as
 18    (select distinct rank from test),
 19  all_depts_ranks as
 20    (select d.dept, r.rank
 21     from all_depts d cross join all_ranks r
 22    )
```

Finally, perform outer join and use conditional aggregation to produce desired result:

```
 23  select a.dept,
 24    max(case when a.rank = 1 then nvl2(t.id, '1', '0') || '/' || a.rank end) r1,
 25    max(case when a.rank = 2 then nvl2(t.id, '1', '0') || '/' || a.rank end) r2,
 26    max(case when a.rank = 3 then nvl2(t.id, '1', '0') || '/' || a.rank end) r3,
 27    max(case when a.rank = 4 then nvl2(t.id, '1', '0') || '/' || a.rank end) r4
 28  from all_depts_ranks a left join test t on t.dept = a.dept and t.rank = a.rank
 29  group by a.dept
 30  order by a.dept;

DEPT R1    R2    R3    R4
---- ----- ----- ----- -----
CSE  1/1   1/2   1/3   1/4
ELEC 0/1   1/2   0/3   0/4
MECH 1/1   1/2   1/3   1/4

SQL>
```